# actian JCL example

Tags: java, pervasive

Does anyone have an example of retrieving data using Actian's JCL to a loosely coupled pervasive database in Java? The database I am connecting to only has DAT files. My goal is to create a link between pervasive and MS SQL.

I am not looking for a freebie, but someone to point me in the right direction so I can learn and grow.

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this in my archives. Don't know when it was written, whether it works, or if this interface is still supported. You don't say what version of PSQL you're using so I don't even know if this will work with your version.

```
import pervasive.database.*;

public class VersionTest implements Consts
{
public VersionTest()
{
try
{
Session session = Driver.establishSession(); 
Database db = session.connectToDatabase("PMKE:"); 
XCursor xcursor = db.createXCursor(57000); 
//Using local TABL.DAT (length 255 assures no leftovers!)
xcursor.setKZString(0,255,"plsetup\\tabl.dat");
//Open the file to load local MKDE
int status = xcursor.BTRV(BTR_OPEN);
System.out.println("Local Open status: " + status);
//Using remote TABL.DAT (length 255 assures no leftovers!)

xcursor.setKZString(0,255,"h:\\basic2c\\develop\\tabl.dat");
//set the buffer size
xcursor.setDataSize(15);
//get version 
status = xcursor.BTRV(BTR_VERSION);
System.out.println("Version status: " + status);
// should be 15, always prints 5
System.out.println("Version length: " + xcursor.getRecLength());
System.out.println("Version: " + xcursor.getDString(0,15));

// try with an open file on a server
XCursor xcursor2 = db.createXCursor(57000); 
//Using remote TABL.DAT (length 255 assures no leftovers!)

xcursor2.setKZString(0,255,"h:\\basic2c\\develop\\tabl.dat");
//Open the file
status = xcursor2.BTRV(BTR_OPEN);
System.out.println("Remote Open status: " + status);
//set the buffer size
xcursor2.setDataSize(15);
//get version 
status = xcursor2.BTRV(BTR_VERSION);
System.out.println("Version status: " + status);
// should be 15, always prints 5
System.out.println("Version length: " + xcursor2.getRecLength());
System.out.println("Version: " + xcursor2.getDString(0,15));

// clean up resources 
Driver.killAllSessions();
}catch(Exception exp)
{
exp.printStackTrace();
}
}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
new VersionTest();
}
}
```

Comment: this looks great. I am using PSQL version 12. I will give this a try, learn from it and I am sure it will work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

JCL APIs are still supported with Actian PSQL v12 and v13.
You can find more documentation on retrieving data using Actian JCL at
http://docs.pervasive.com/products/database/psqlv12/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=jcl/java_api.2.2.html

To link to MS Sql Server you would need to create the data dictionary files(DDFs) for the PSQl data files to use with relational interfaces.